# Div produced from an ASP.Net GridView is too large

Tags: asp.net, html

I have an ASP.Net GridView with properties like so:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdOrderEntry" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="True"
                                    DataKeyNames="oid" Height="100%">
```

When I view the control in the browser, there is a lot of white space after the control.  When viewing the HTML, the div that is produced by the GridView is much larger than the control, causing the whitespace.  Is there a property I can set on the GridView to make the div as small as possible?

Comment: can't you put the GridView in another div and style such parent div?

Comment: does the container that the Gridview is in have a fixed height? if so having `Height="100%"` is just inheriting that container's height. in that case just do as @DavidePiras has suggested

Comment: There was an unnecessary CSS Friendly control adapter interfering with the display of this control.  I resolved this issue by removing the height property and removing the control.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is being caused by your Height="100%" attribute, remove that, and it should just stretch around the table it contains (unless there is some css other style added to it as well).

Comment: If I remove this, then it will not display in FireFox or Chrome.

Comment: it should, unless there is some other styling used that is breaking it - I never apply a height attribute and do all my developing in Firefox first.

Answer (score 3):

If you set the `CssClass` property you will be able to create some css to address the problem. I would recommend using a live css editor so you can mess around with it until you get the desired effect.